# Cannot build project with MSBuild programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, target, targets

I am trying to package a Visual Studio .csproj with MSBuild programmatically (using namespace Microsoft.Build.Evaluation).
I can correctly package this project with command like like

```
    MSBuild "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestMvc\TestMvc\TestMvc.csproj" /T:Package
```

But when I use the following code (I implemented my own logger, but it does not matter here):

```
            var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestMvc\TestMvc\TestMvc.csproj");

            var logger = new OutputLogger(_panel);
            List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger> loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>();
            loggers.Add(logger);
            var targets = new string[] 
            { 
                "Package"

            };
            var result = project.Build(targets, loggers);
    Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.UnloadProject(project);
```

Solution is not built. Logger gives me an error "Output file "obj\Debug\TestMvc.dll" does not exist."

After I build this project in Visual Studio manually (when all the binaries are successfully built), then this code packages the project succesfully. So there are all nesessary binaries available already.

The question is: why "Package" target launched programmatically is not equal to "Package" lanunched by command line and how to force the former do the same action as its commandlike counterpart?

**UPD.**
To see what's happening I enabled diagnostics output in both cases. What I've got:
Console command produced the following log:

```
Target "CoreCompile: (TargetId:37)" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" from project "D:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcTest2\MvcTest3\MvcTest3.csproj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Building target "CoreCompile" completely.
Output file "obj\Debug\MvcTest3.dll" does not exist.
Using "Csc" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Csc" (TaskId:20)
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe .....
  Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1 (TaskId:20)
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. (TaskId:20)
   (TaskId:20)
Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:20)
```

When calling from API, I got the following log:

```
Target "CoreCompile" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets":
Building target "CoreCompile" completely.
Output file "obj\Debug\MvcTest3.dll" does not exist.
Using "Csc" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Csc"
Done executing task "Csc".
```

So Csc task is launched in both cases, however, it does not produce any output files when launched by API (i checked this even in file monitor, no files are produced).

Comment: What's the working directory in each case?

obj\Debug\etc... is a relative path not an absolute one.

Comment: @Murph, the same directories. I just removed long path in both cases for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function, *RunCommandLines(string[] commands)* that runs command lines as if they were run from the command prompt. The trick is that you need to run the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 20XX" and then run MSBuild.

My first command line.

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

The second command runs the MSBuild.exe:

```
MSBuild \"C:\\PathToYourProject\\ProjectFile.csproj\" /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU
```

Final Solution:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public void CreateReleaseBuild(string projectFilePath)
{           
    List<string> commandLines = new List<string> {
        "%comspec% /k \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\"",
        string.Format( "MSBuild \"{0}\" /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU", projectFilePath),
    };
    string results = RunCommandLines( commandLines.ToArray() );         
}

private string RunCommandLines( string[] commands )
{
    string commandPromptOutput = string.Empty;
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo( "cmd" );
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    using( Process process = Process.Start( info ) )
    {
        StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;
        StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;

        foreach( string command in commands )
        {
            sw.WriteLine( command );
        }

        sw.Close();
        commandPromptOutput= sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return commandPromptOutput;
}
```

The project will be built to the *bin* folder located where the csproj file is stored. You can choose "Release" or "Debug" builds by using `/p:Configuration=Debug` with the second command line.